# Wordpress admin account was deleted in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

i was created a wordpress website and i deleted mistakenly main admin account from phpmyadmin database. now i cannot log into my dashboard of wordpress. please help me to make a admin account to log into my website,.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaMYy.jpg)

[the user that you see it is not an admin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaMYy.jpg) i want to promote him as admin. could you tell me how to do it

Comment: add a record manullay in DB for admin

Answer (score 0):

You can run below SQL query in your phpmyadmin to create new admin account.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`) VALUES ('newadmin', MD5('pass123'), 'firstname lastname', 'email@example.com', '0');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Please replace your password with pas123 in above query. Also if you are using table prefix other than wp_ then update it to in above queries.

You can also make your existing account as admin using following queries.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, 2, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, 2, 'wp_user_level', '10');
```